# Angular2 RxJS Observable Search field filter chaining

Tags: angular, rxjs, array-filter

I have an Angular2 CLI app with a search component that need to do a deep search. By which I mean, When the user, searching for all users by  their name with birth dates within the last 40 years, starts typing in the letters of the name and the searchService then first gets all user objects whose names contain those letters, followed by another filter on each object that compares the dates of birth (stored in another object linked by user id) and returns only user objects whose dob is within past 40 years.

Search field

```
<input (keyup)="search()" type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchTerms" />
```

Results

```
<div *ngFor="let result of finalResults | async">
   {{result.name}}
</div>
```

Component Code

```
finalResults = searchTerms
  .debounceTime(300)      
  .distinctUntilChanged()   
  .switchMap(term => {
    return searchService1.search(term)
      .map(items => items.filter(item => {
           searchService2.search(item.id)
            .map(results => results.filter(result => result.dob>1977))
            })
      )
  })
  .catch(handleError);
```

The behavior I see is that, as long as the search term has matching letters, the results contain those users, but the dob filter is ignored.

Comment: I don't understand why you have `searchService1.search` and `searchService2.search`? What are the differences ?

Comment: @Maxime - I have two different types of objects that have their own accessor services. When I have the first object, I use it to retrieve the second and filter it based on values in the second object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to filter synchronously using an asynchronous value. The `searchService2` is returning asynchronously yet you are trying to filter based on the value of the `Observable` which is a always truthy.

You need to flatten the second stream into the first.

Something like the following should be more inline with what you need.

```
finalResults = searchTerms
  .debounceTime(300)      
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  // Flatten each search result from the first search service 
  .switchMap(term => searchService1.search(term))
  // Flatten the returned items into the stream
  .switchMap(items => items)
  // Initiate the second search and map the dob into the returned object
  .switchMap(
    item => searchService2.search(item.id)
  )
  // Flatten the secondary results
  .switchMap(items => items)
  // Filter each of the items
  .filter(({dob}) => dob > 1977)  
  .catch(handleError);
```

Comment: Thanks @paulpdaniels. I see your point. I'm not very clear about the role of switchMap but giving your suggestion a go. Getting the following error on every search -  'Type Error - You provided Undefined where a stream was expected...' EDIT - I think a return statement is expected somewhere down the chain.